# How write MemoryStream data to file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, streaming

I have this code:

```
private void SaveStreamToFile(string fileFullPath, Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream.Length == 0) return;

        // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
        {
            // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);

            // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
            fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
        }
    }
```

I call this method like this SaveStreamToFile(@"f:\Test.txt", memoryStream);

I got error:File operation not permitted. Access to path 'f:\Test.txt' is denied.

Comment: You don't have to pull the bytes out of the stream, use `stream.CopyTo(fileStream);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, presumably that means you don't have write access to `f:\Test.txt`. That's a problem outside the scope of .NET, really.

However, your method is broken. Here:

```
byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
```

you're *assuming* that you can get the length of the stream (not all streams support this), and you're also *assuming* that `Read` will read the whole thing in one go. That's not necessarily the case.

If you're using .NET 4, you can use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx), which will make life a lot simpler. (Although that won't help you to abort if there's no data in the stream.) But you'll still need to fix the inability to write to `f:\Test.txt` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error also and, like Jon Skeet suggests, the first issue was the access rights.

This was because I did not use a relative path to reach the destination folder. Once I changed this it allowed me to access and amend without trouble.